# declaring a vary generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic

In my project I have 2 interfaces.

`IButtonInputHandler<T>` &  `INumericInputHandler<T>`

Now I want to create a class that gets the first interface\the second interface\both of them and exposes methods based on their types. For example, if I build the class with `IButtonInputHandler<Buttons>` and `INumericInputHandler<Scroller>`, I want to expose two functions that receive Button and Scroller objects.

If I build the class with only `IButtonInputHandler<Keys>`, I want to expose a function that will receive a Buttons object.

To be clear -- if I leave the option to use 2 types dynamically my class will be like this:

`Class<T>` and the method will return T.

Basically I need the flexibility to sometimes use 1 type and sometimes use 2 types.

Comment: What do you mean by "build the class"? Do you understand that the members available on a type are defined by the *type* at compile-time, not dependent on anything available at execution time? (You can make some members throw an exception of course, but the members themselves will still be present...)

Comment: sorry for not being clear.
the class is not to be generated at run time. it is to let other programmers to use the class in their code with their choice of interfaces or interfaces

Comment: I think defining an interface that has the desired behaviour for the comp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make three classes:

```
public class ButtonInputHandler<T> : IButtonInputHandler<T>
{
    //implement IButtonInputHandler<T> here
}

public class NumericInputHandler<T> : INumericInputHandler<T>
{
    //implement INumericInputHandler<T> here
}

public class ButtonAndNumericInputHandler<TButton, TNumeric> :
    ButtonInputHandler<TButton>, INumericInputHandler<TNumeric>
{
    //implement INumericInputHandler<TNumeric> here
    //(the implementation for IButtonInputHandler<TButton> will be inherited)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), however there is no OR option when adding multiple constraints.

What you will need to do is create a 3rd interface (or base class) that `T` must implement. For your original example, if `Buttons` and `Scroller` both implement `IInputs` you can declare your interfaces as

```
public interface IButtonInputHandler<T>  where T : IInputs
{
}

public interface INumericInputHandler<T>  where T : IInputs
{

}
```

Comment: The problem is not with the type of the input interfaces.
i want the 3rd class to be able to use one type of IButtonInputHandler or INumericInputHandler or both of them and not let it use two types of the same interface

i.e.
ClassX<T1,T2> or ClassX<T1> or ClassX<T2>